# What can I use to provide a webmail interface on a Linux system without using IMAP/POP?

Tags: linux, web-apps, email-server

I have a Linux VPS on which there's no GUI, and no IMAP/POP server.  What I would like to do is provide a "webmail" style interface to e-mail on that system - all I have for e-mail there right now is Alpine from an SSH session, which is less than optimal for me.  I'd like to be able to use a web browser on a remote system to connect to it and read/send mail.

Things that I would consider to be "must have" for what I want to do would be:

- Read and send mail via a web browser talking to my VPS
- Read e-mail from /var/spool/mail type files on the local disk of the VPS, and maintain the data in that form (because I might also want to operate on it later using something like Alpine or mailx, I don't want the webmail reader to reorganize it such that other programs can't read it after the webmail reader touches it).
- Deliver outgoing mail by sending it through the local MTA, as if it were a local mail client.

Things that would be really nice to have, but not absolutely required:

- Self-contained (doesn't need to be plugged into Apache or Nginx, or anything like that).

Things that would absolutely disqualify a potential solution from consideration:

- Needs to fetch the mail from an IMAP or POP server, even if on the local system - has to operate directly on the mail files in the filesystem.
- Stores the mail in a database, in a different kind of directory hierarchy (like MH does), or in any way other than just the raw mail files.

I used something like this quite a while ago, but I can't remember for the life of me what it was called...  The things I've come across recently that are closest to what I want would be [Neomail](https://sourceforge.net/projects/neomail/) and [Open WebMail](http://www.openwebmail.org/), but even they have to be plugged into an existing web server, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Can anyone point me towards a webmail system that works in this way?  Am I just crazy thinking that I remember that there was once such a thing...?  Something that has to be built from source is fine, I don't need it to be packaged for the distro I'm using (though in case there **is** something already packaged, I'm using Fedora...).